# Counter increment on setInterval

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

```
import React from 'react';
import {Plugins} from '@capacitor/core';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {db} from './Firebase';



const Maps = () => {

const [lat, setLat] = useState(0);
const [long, setLong] = useState(0);
const [count, setCount] = useState (0);

const Counter = () => {
  setCount(count + 1)
  console.log(count)
}


const Location = () => {


      Plugins.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(
        result => setLat ( result.coords.latitude)
      )

      Plugins.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(
        result => setLong (result.coords.longitude)
      )
}




const interval = () => {
  setInterval (() =>
  {
    Location();
   Counter();
  }, 5000 );

}



    return (
        <div>
          <div>
            <button onClick = {interval}>
              Get Location
            </button>
             </div>
            <div>
               {long}
            </div>
              <div>
                {lat}
              </div>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Maps;
```

I'm trying to get the counter to increment on every iteration of setInterval, through the counter function, but when I log count, it does not increment and always remains as 0.

I've tried running setCount itself within setInterval without any success, it still does not increment count.

Comment: Why are you using two differents states for location coordinates?

Comment: I don't know, I tried to do it in the same state but I kept tripping over it, so I just went with the easier way, I'm pretty sure there's better ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @BrianThompson answer. Try this to avoid innecessary rerenders

```
import React from 'react';
import {Plugins} from '@capacitor/core';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {db} from './Firebase';



const Maps = () => {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    latLng:{lat:0,lng:0},
    counter: 0
  })
  const interval = useRef()

  //Use camelCase for methods
  const location = () => {
      Plugins.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(
        result => setState ( ({counter}) => {
            counter = counter+1
            console.log(counter)
            return ({
               latLng: {
                  lat: result.coords.latitude, 
                  lng: result.coords.longitude
               },
               counter
            })
         })
      )
  }

  const startInterval = () => {
      if(interval.current) return;
      interval.current = setInterval (() => {
        location();
      }, 5000 );
   }

  const stopInterval = () ={
    clearInterval(interval.current)
    interval.current = null
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    //Because interval is causing state updates, remember to clear interval when component will unmount
    return stopInterval    
  },[])



    return (
        <div>
          <div>
            <button onClick = {startInterval}>
              Get Location
            </button>
             </div>
            <div>
               {state.latLng.lng}
            </div>
              <div>
                {state.latLng.lat}
              </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Its a stale closure. Change to this `setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)`.

Using the updater form of set state like above, you can guarantee that you will be using the most recent value of state.

You can think of it as `count` in your function being a snapshot of what its value was when the `setInterval` was declared. This will stop your updates from appearing to work.

In addition, setting state is async, so the `console.log(count)` will most likely not reflect the new value. Log in an effect or outside the function body to see the updated value each render.

A note about your implementation:
You are creating a `setInterval` each time the button is clicked. This could lead to some interesting side-effects if clicked more than once. If you click the button twice for example, you will have two `setIntervals` running every 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.On  the setInterval button implementation, I really hadn't thought about that I was testing out some logic but definitely I'll now look into that implementation, thanks.